# Outlook connection status window missing "Local Mailbox" tab

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-365

I need to monitor sync progress for newly added Outlook accounts.  Googling how to do this, resulted in this method on multiple sites:

> CTRL + Right click the Outlook status icon in the system tray and click "Connection Status"

[image]

I tested it on my machine this morning and it was there and reliably reflected sync status and activity.  However, 5 of the 5 users I've migrated today DO not have this tab.

How do I get the "Local Mailbox" tab in the "Outlook Connection Status" window to show up?

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, please ensure that the following conditions are met:

1. There are Exchange accounts configured on their Outlook desktop client.
2. Start Outlook client in Cached mode.

For your reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4e72c94a-dbf2-4a56-86c3-3e28153c2a34/missing-outlook-connection-tab-in-windows-10?forum=outlook

Hope this can be helpful.